# Sockets with router port fowarding causes slow connection. How can I fix that?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp

I have been making a online java game for the past months. The connection worked great over LAN(hamachi) with my local pc but not with external devices. I tried with router port fowarding (which is more interesting than hamachi) from an external PC but the connection is as slow (about 4 sec delay)...
I thought that the network algorith from my game was not effective so I created a simple program that sends via TCP/IP small packages and the result are as slow. I also tried to turn off my firewall and my antivirus, but the tests didn't show any change.

**Can anyone explain me how to decrease the latency of the connection or why Java Sockets are that slow?** 
(I use the router Linksys model no: WRT54G, with Eclipse IDE)
Help is greatly appreciated.

Here are the logs from my testing program:

**ON LOCAL PC...**

trying to connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx... (from router port fowarding)
Sent 10 request... (avg: 238 ms)
For 10 request, 4631 miliseconds has elapsed.

trying to connect to Phil-PC... (from hamachi local network)
Sent 10 request... (avg: 0 ms)
For 10 request, 10 miliseconds has elapsed.

**ON EXTERNAL PC...**

trying to connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx... (from router port fowarding)
Sent 10 request... (avg: 235 ms)
For 10 request, 4418 miliseconds has elapsed.

trying to connect to Phil-PC... (from hamachi local network)
Sent 10 request... (avg: 245 ms)
For 10 request, 4808 miliseconds has elapsed.

Here's the source code
With setTcpNoDelay(true) added, it took half the time to complete 10 requests.
«For 10 request, 2136 miliseconds has elapsed.» I will try it in my game tonight or tomorrow !

```css
package segp10039402;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class DebugServer {

 static ServerSocket server;
 
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  DebugServer debugServer = new DebugServer();
 }

 public DebugServer()
 {
  try
  {
   server = new ServerSocket(2620);
   new Thread(accept).start();
   createInterface();
  }
  catch(IOException ex)
  {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error: " + ex.getMessage(), "Alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
   System.exit(0);
  }
 }
 
 private void createInterface() 
 {
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  JLabel label = new JLabel("Server");
  frame.add(label);
  frame.setVisible(true);
 }

 private static Runnable accept = new Runnable()
 {
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
   ObjectOutputStream oos;
   ObjectInputStream ois;
   
   while(true)
   {
    Socket socket;
    try
    {
     System.out.println("Server is online...");
     socket = server.accept();
     System.out.println("New connection...");
     for (int i=0; i<10;++i)
     {
      System.out.println("=================="+i+"======================");
      //receive send
      ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
      long packet = (long) ois.readObject();
      oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
      System.out.println("Client ping: "+(long)(System.currentTimeMillis()-packet)+" ms");
      //send
      oos.writeObject(System.currentTimeMillis());
      oos.flush();
      //receive
      ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
      packet = (long) ois.readObject();
      System.out.println("Server ping: "+packet+" ms");
     }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();} catch (ClassNotFoundException e){e.printStackTrace();}
   }
  }
 };
}
```

```html
package segp10049302;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class DebugClient 
{
 public static Socket socket;
 public final int TOTAL_REQUEST = 10;
 
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  DebugClient debugClient = new DebugClient();
 }
 
 public DebugClient()
 {
  createInterface();
  createConnection();
 }
 
 public void createConnection()
 {
  try 
  {
   int port = 2620;
   String ip = "184.163.171.xxx"; 
   //String ip = "Phil-PC";
   System.out.println("trying to connect to "+ip+"...");
   socket = new Socket(ip, port);
   socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
   ObjectOutputStream oos;
   ObjectInputStream ois;
   //send
   long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
   for (int i=0; i<10;++i)
   {
    System.out.println("=================="+i+"======================");
    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    oos.writeObject(System.currentTimeMillis());
    oos.flush();
    System.out.println("Sent current time");
    //receive
    ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    long incomingPacket = (long) ois.readObject();
    long incomingPing = (long)(System.currentTimeMillis()-incomingPacket);
    System.out.println("Client ping: "+ incomingPing+" ms");
    //send
    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    oos.writeObject(incomingPing);
    oos.flush();
   }
   long totalTimeElapsed = (long)((System.currentTimeMillis()-currentTime));
   System.out.println("For "+TOTAL_REQUEST+" request, "+totalTimeElapsed+" miliseconds has elapsed.");
  }
  catch (UnknownHostException e) 
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } 
  catch (IOException e)
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
 
 private void createInterface() 
 {
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  JLabel label = new JLabel("Client");
  frame.add(label);
  frame.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

Comment: first of all, have you enabled `Socket.setTcpNoDelay(true)` ?

Comment: Please post code for both client and server.

Comment: You said yourself that Java sockets *aren't* that slow, on your LAN. Why would they magically become slow through a router? It doesn't make sense. Try looking in the right place. This is *clearly* a network problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers.I posted the code and also tried setTcpNoDelay(true) and it decreased the total time by half ! I will try it in my game tonight or tomorrow to see if it's better!! Here's the log with the edits: «For 10 request, 2136 miliseconds has elapsed.»